# Expo EAS environment variables and secrets values not fully recognised during builds

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm configuring my app so that avoid committing any data to git that I don't want (firebase json/plist files, SSO ID's, etc.) and using eas secrets to provide them at build.

I've followed the instructions on https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/, however there are a few issues I've encountered.

My `app.config.ts` file is as follows:

```js
import { ExpoConfig, ConfigContext } from "expo/config"
import * as dotenv from "dotenv"

dotenv.config()
dotenv.config({ path: ".env.local", override: true })

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
  ...config,
  ios: {
    ...config.ios,
    googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_PLIST
  },
  android: {
    ...config.android,
    googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON
  },
  plugins: [
    ...config.plugins || [],
    [
      "react-native-fbsdk-next",
      {
        appID: process.env.SSO_FB_APPID,
        clientToken: process.env.SSO_FB_CLIENT_TOKEN,
        displayName: "my-app",
        scheme: `fb${process.env.SSO_FB_APPID}`,
      }
    ],
  ]
})
```

When running a build with eas, in the **Read app config** step I can see that it's successfully parsed `app.json` and `app.config.ts` together: (output truncated)

```
Using app configuration
{
  "name": "my-app"
  ...
  "ios" {
    ...
    "googleServicesFile": "/home/expo/workingdir/environment-secrets/8feexxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx6649" // Redaction made by me
  },
  "android":
    ...
    "googleServicesFile": "/home/expo/workingdir/environment-secrets/b8b2xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx6e77" // Redaction made by me
  }
  "plugins": [
    ...
    [
      "react-native-fbsdk-next",
      {
        "appID": "****************", // Redactions made by eas
        "clientToken": "********************************",
        "displayName": "my-app",
        "scheme": "fb****************"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

But I error at the **Prebuild** step:

```
[stderr] CommandError: missing appID in the plugin properties
```

Which is referring to the `appID` property for the `react-native-fbsdk-next` plugin.

I can also confirm that the secrets are available at build. In the **Spin up build environment** step, I see:

```
Environment secrets:
  GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON=/home/expo/workingdir/environment-secrets/b8b2xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx6e77 // Redactions made by me
  GOOGLE_SERVICES_PLIST=/home/expo/workingdir/environment-secrets/8feexxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx6649
  SSO_FB_APPID=********  // Redactions made by eas
  SSO_FB_CLIENT_TOKEN=********
```

I've seen some stuff placing environment variables in `eas.json`, however I must be misinterpreting it as that defeats the whole point of secrets if you have to put them in in plaintext and commit them to my repository?
As you can see, I'm storing client secrets (SSO for FB and google services files), so they're not exactly "secrets", but it doesn't feel right committing them into my repository, especially since the [Expo documentation uses google service files as examples of things to not commit](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#how-to-upload-a-secret-file-and-use-it-in-my-app-config)

Furthermore, if I run the build locally, and move my `react-native-fbsdk-next` config into my `app.json` file and hardcode the values, I then run into issues with the google services file:

```
[PREBUILD] Error: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: Path to google-services.json is not defined. Please specify the `expo.android.googleServicesFile` field in app.json.
```

..so the issue is just moving around to anything related to env vars, and it's not specific to the plugin config.

Given that I've been able to confirm that my environment variables are indeed set, and that they are being transpired into the `app.json` the build is using, I'm not sure where else to go from here.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Are you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: I have no idea why, but building another project from scratch solved this. What doesn't make sense, is that I copied over every file (config and app related files alike) and it worked as expected. My best guess is that there may be a bug in EAS and my project ID was now problematic. Perhaps some local cache might solve the issue? Not entirely sure unfortunately :(
I still have a snapshot of my project if any Expo devs are interested, I just don't have the time to debug it any further.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact issue as you. The problem (for me at least) was that on Expo SDK 49+, I would need to prefix my environment variables with `EXPO_PUBLIC_` for auto-inlining to work. Loading all your variables in `app.config.ts` would not be enough, as this only made them available to the Expo CLI, the Metro bundler would not be aware of them.

The fact the build environment can access these variables, doesn't mean they will be bundled in the actual JS/TS files. In Webpack we use the `EnvironmentPlugin` to load them, in Metro it's done automatically for prefixed varaibles.

Alternatively if you don't like the prefix approach, you can use [react-native-dotnev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) with a type declaration file to achieve the same.

Note this is strictly for local builds. If you are using EAS Build, you are best off using the recommended approach of defining non-sensitive variables in `eas.json`, and use EAS Secrets to expose and inline sensitive ones.

Comment: So it means that if I have a sensitive variable, I register it in EAS Secrets, but in order to access it during build time, I still have to use the prefix `EXPO_PUBLIC_`? Otherwise it won't work?